# How to setup outgoing mail server through outlook office365 in odoo 9

Tags: python-2.7, outlook, office365, odoo-9

I will try to setup outgoing mail server in odoo 9 .so i fill all the field and test connection and the connection also success , but at the time of send mail it will generate an error .

Field fill like that:-

Name : sendmail

Priority: 10

SMTP Server : smtp.office365.com

SMTP Port:25

Debugging: enable

Connection Security:TLS (STARTTLS)

Username:my yser name

Password:password

But, when we send any mail then it will generate the below error

```
  16-12-06 10:04:28,440 426 INFO test openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_mail_server: Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'smtp.office365.com'.
 SMTPDataError: 550
 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
 2016-12-06 10:04:28,443 426 ERROR test  openerp.addons.mail.models.mail_mail: failed sending mail (id: 136) due to             Mail Delivery Failed
 Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'smtp.office365.com'.
 SMTPDataError: 550
 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 262, in send
 res = IrMailServer.send_email(msg,  mail_server_id=mail.mail_server_id.id)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
 return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 490, in new_api
 result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 483, in send_email
 raise MailDeliveryException(_("Mail Delivery Failed"), msg)
 MailDeliveryException: (u'Mail Delivery Failed', u"Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'smtp.office365.com'.\nSMTPDataError: 550\n5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender")
```

So i tried too much for this , but i am not getting any solution , if you have any solutin , please share with me .

Comment: I think, you should checked *enable access* in your *Office365* account settings. There are some firewall or access disable restrict to send email via your account.

Answer (score 0):

Use port 587.

The error message tells you that the sender is invalid - you can only send as the mailbox owner (primary SMTP address) or as one of the proxy addresses associated with the mailbox.

Comment: Thanx@Dmitry Streblechenko , for your reply , i am alos use port 587 , but the same error are arise .

Comment: As I said before, the sender is wrong - SMTP does not like it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all catchall parameters (mail.catchall.domain and mail.catchall.alias) under "Settings" -> "Technical" -> "Parameters" -> "System Parameters" and it work like charm .

Answer (score 0):

WORKS LIKE CHARM :

Removing all catchall parameters (mail.catchall.domain and mail.catchall.alias) under "Settings" -> "Technical" -> "Parameters" -> "System Parameters" and it work like charm . TY Debasish

Comment: welcome@Venkadesh, Its request plz up vote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Odoo V12

It was not suffisient for my problem, I had to delete the alias domain but there another thing to check :

I initialy created my odoo installation with a GMAIL address, worked a bit but had to switch for a pro e-mail because all my invitations e-mail was blocked by Google Bot beacause it look liked suspicious. It did this only in Odoo v12 because there is more links in the mail.

So I configured my real smtp server in Odoo but get the error 550. Odoo kept in the COMPANY settings the primary gmail address and tried to send on my other smtp server with the gmail name. The other server didn't accepted it so sent me back error 550.

Once i putted my new e-mail address in the company description, and deleted alias domain it worked !!

PS : Don't try to edit ir_mail_server.py to put in bruteforce your e-mail ... Doesn't work ..